# Is it better for two threads to use two lists or one synchronized list?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

If you had thread #1 that iterates over a list and uses the data to render 2d graphics, and then thread #2 that is deleting items, adding items, but mostly changing the value of items in that list, which option is better/more efficient?

Option 1:

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();

// Thread 2

ArrayList<Object> newData = new ArrayList<Object>();
newData.add(new Object());

list2 = newData;


// Thread 1

list1 = list2;

for (Object o : list1) {
// use data to render
}
```

Option 2:

```
List<Object> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Object>());

// Thread 2

synchronized(list) {
// add, remove, change values
}

// Thread 1

synchronized(list) {
    for (Object o : list) {
    // use data to render
    }
}
```

I know very little about how this works but I'm scared that in the second option, thread 1 could be trying to iterate the list and it's locked so thread 1 runs slow and this is visible because it's being rendered. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Neither. If you use two lists your second thread will miss updates, or at least it isn't clear how they are equivalent to a single list. Use a single synchronized list, or synchronization, but that's not sufficient either: if you iterate over a list you have to synchronize on it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 2**

Because, if you do not synchronize it, `Concurrent Read/Write Exception` Thrown.

Either way, if there are more than one thread access to a `Generic Collection`, You have to lock Read/Write operation. otherwise, You might encounter exception.

**Basic Collection Read/Write Rule:**

Ultimate Concurrent Read But 1 for Modifying Collection

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 will not work. 
It seems to you that you have created 2 lists, but this line `list1=list2` will not copy list1 to list2 it will change the pointer to point on the same array.
If you want to copy list1 into list2 it will force you to iterate over list1 and you will get the concurrent read write exception.

So Option2 is better.

Comment: I know that I'm not creating a deep clone, list2 is constantly being set to a new list so the list that list1 was last set to will have been dropped by all but list1, no?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "will have been dropped by all but list1" but you need to keep in mind that objects like lists (unlike premitive types) will only change the object they are pointing to when doing something like list1=list2. That means that now list1 and list two are pointing to the same place in the memory heap and any change on list1 will occur on list2 because theyh are practically the same object.